# how will i convert an if less than condition to hardware in digital?

Tags: digital-logic

i have a condition like if a number less than a constant ,then how can this be converted into hardware in digital design.Will this be converted into mux or something else?

Comment: I think you're going to clear this up a bit. Are you asking what an 'if a < b' statement will look like as digital logic?

Comment: Are a and b two analog quantities (voltages or currents) that need to be compared, or are they some kind of digital quantities, e.g. 8 bit numbers available on two separate 8 bit buses, or what?

Comment: Also, signed or unsigned?

Comment: yes if(a<b) how it is in digital logic.a is got from some calculations and b is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a subtractor. You subtract a from b, and th sign bit will tell you < or >=. By the way, for <= you can either check for all zeroes, or just swap a and b.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try developing something like an N bit digital comparator for unsigned integers. How would we compare two numbers \$ A=A_{N-1}...A_1A_0\$ and \$ B=B_{N-1}...B_1B_0\$ ? 
 Here is the algorithm: 
1) If \$A_{N-1} = B_{N-1}\$ then return the result of \$A' < B'\$, where \$ A=A_{N-2}...A_1A_0\$ and \$ B=B_{N-2}...B_1B_0\$, i.e. the original numbers without their MSB.
2) Otherwise return the result of \$A_{N-1} < B_{N-1}\$ (just the relation of the two current bits).

So here is the basic block `CMP1`: Bit compare of \$A_i\$ with \$B_i\$, if \$A_i<B_i\$, return `1`, otherwise return the result of next comparison. Here is the truth table:

```
Ai    Bi   Result_(i-1) |  Result_i
0     0        0        |    0
0     0        1        |    1
0     1        0        |    1
0     1        1        |    1
1     0        0        |    0
1     0        1        |    0
1     1        0        |    0
1     1        1        |    1
```

And for the N-bit we just chain the blocks:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxTP2m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>